# Inherit Dependency injection

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to create a generic api service in order to make model-related services easier to create:

```
export abstract class ModelService<T> {

    constructor(protected apiService: ApiService) {
        //ApiService is a service that wraps Http and adds signature , auth and serialization.
    }

    public getAll(): Observable<T[]> {
        return this.apiService.get<T[]>(this.modelClass, this.baseUrl);
    }
}
```

then, I will create my service that manages model `Foo`:

```
@Injectabe()
export class FooService extends ModelService<Foo>{

}
```

But when I call `fooService.getAll().subscribe(...);` I get an error saying that `apiService` is undefined (cannot get property 'get' of undefined).

So the fix is to add a constructor in `FooService` like this:

```
constructor(api: ApiService) {
    super(api);
}
```

But problem is that it's not dev-friendly, nothing tells you to do so and since `FooService` extends `ModelService`, it should have the same constructor and therefore the same dependencies.

Is there any way to inherit dependency?

PS: I already tried to add `@Injectable()` to `ModelService`, same error.

EDIT: `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "",
    "declaration": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [
      "es6",
      "dom"
    ],
    "mapRoot": "./",
    "module": "es6",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "outDir": "../dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "../node_modules/@types"
    ]
  }
}
```

`package.json`:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/core": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/forms": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/http": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/router": "3.2.1",
    ...
    ...
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "2.2.1",
    ... 
    ...
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For child class that doesn't introduce extra dependencies and doesn't need its own `constructor` it is

```
@Injectable()
export abstract class ModelService<T> {...}

export class FooService extends ModelService<Foo>{

}
```

`@Injectable()` decorator is needed for parent class (if it uses type annotation and not `@Inject`). No `@Injectable()` decorator is needed for child class.

For children classes that may have their own dependencies and thus need own constructors the dependencies should be explicitly passed to `super` (see the other answer). In JavaScript, rest operator and `@Inject` may be used to skip some tautology, but for TypeScript it is safe to enumerate all constructor parameters explicitly.

Comment: I tried to remove `@Injectable()` from my `FooService` and added it to `ModelService`, still same problem with dependency injection. So there's no way to handle it properly without explicitly passing dependencies using constructor?

Comment: It should work as intended. http://plnkr.co/edit/WwslqHcOUxKj4tQxIs23?p=preview Please, provide [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if you have a problem that can be replicated.

Comment: The code in the question doesn't have constructor in FooService. If you need a constructor then sure, you need `@Injectable` or `@Inject` there.

Comment: That's weird, it works in your plunkr, when I copy-paste in my AppModule, it doesn't. I forked your plunker to test some other possiblities and I added my version of @angular in config.js, it's still working (only in plunkr). I edited question to add tsconfig.json and package.json.

Comment: Not sure what may cause this. I would suggest to try also explicit annotation, i.e. `constructor(@Inject(ApiService) protected apiService: ApiService) {`. `@Injectable` is not necessary anywhere in this case.

Comment: I think the problem could be webpack (I'm using angular-cli). Anyways I have the same error using an explicit `@Inject(Foo)`.

Answer (score 5):

The constructor needs to repeat the dependencies and then passed to the super class using `super(...)`

```
@Injectabe()
export class FooService extends ModelService<Foo>{
    constructor(apiService: ApiService) {
      super(apiService);
        //ApiService is a service that wraps Http and adds signature , auth and serialization.
    }
}
```

This is not an Angular2 requirement or limitation, that's how constructors work in TypeScript.

Comment: If `apiService` has modifier in parent constructor, it should be just `constructor(apiService: ApiService) {` to avoid double assignment.

Comment: Thanks @estus, you're right of course. I was a bit sloppy :-/

Comment: yes I know as I said in the question. Problem here is to find a better way to handle it :/ Nothing planned to handle this case?

Comment: There is nothing to handle. This is how constructors work.

Comment: Problem here is not constructor, it's inheritence I think, since `FooService` should have the same constructor as `ModelService` if I don't explicitly declare one, and thus it should have the same dependency injection needs. The real problem is that my IDE (WebStorm) says "hey, you have to implement the abstract methods of `ModelService`" but no "hey, you have to pass dependencies to parent". So another dev could create a service using `ModelService` and come to me like "dude, it's not working".

Comment: I see what you mean. Perhaps some linter rule to check for constructors of classes with `@Injectable()`. Angular is working on language services to do additional Angular2 related checks. I think that would make sense. Creating a bug report in the Angular2 GitHub repo would be the first step.

Comment: Well @estus's answer seems to work like a charm (in plunkr), but it seems like the issue may come from something else since it's working on plunkr but not in my project, with the exact same angular and typescript versions.

Comment: Glad to hear. Didn't know that.