# what is the best way to programmatically pass a type to a service?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli

Using Angular4 I have created services for different databases. Each databases' actions are the same (kinda like CRUD) but have a different API endpoint (but exactly the same functions.)

I was creating a service for each database but I am thinking there must be a better way to manage this.

Is there a way to pass a "name" to a service during an import or in a component so that the service will know which endpoint should be hit?

Example:

```
import {ApiService} from '../_services/api.service.ts';
```

and in the service:

```
let endpoint = enter code here defined from import of component  
private url = '/api/' + endpoint
```

Comment: sure, but this isn't a good idea. you're making your code brittle and hard to read to save a few lines

Comment: Can you expand on how it makes it brittle? is it better to have 6 150 line services or 1 service extended 6 times?

Comment: 6 150 line services. To achieve this you need to force every consumer to conform to this single service style which will be an inherently error prone process, further, a change in the underlying single service can potentially break your entire application and forces major restructuring, this is what it means to be brittle.  Angular style guide recommends being DRY but not too DRY. this is too DRY.  Angular exposes the http client already which encapsulates the major CRUD operations. There is no reason to have it be any more generic than that.

Comment: thank you @bryan60 I appreciate the explanation. It makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like

```
@Injectable()
abstract class ApiService {
  protected endpoint;

  protected get url() {
    return '/api/' + this.endpoint;
  }

  constructor(protected http: Http) {}

  getItems() {
     return this.http(this.url);
  }
}

class SomeService extends ApiService {
  protected endpoint = 'some';
}
```

Notice that `endpoint` is defined as a field and `url` is read-only accessor, this allows to maintain proper order in child class.

A WETter version (also allows child classes to inject additional dependencies) is:

```
@Injectable()
abstract class ApiService {
  constructor(protected http: Http) {}
  ...      
}

@Injectable()
class SomeService extends ApiService {
  constructor(http: Http /*,  protected some: Some */) {
    super(http);
  }
  ...
}
```

If same dependency persists in both parent and child class, it should have `protected` access modifier in parent class only.

Comment: Accepting this as the answer but as noted by @bryan60 in the question's comments, this could become problematic in future api revisions which should be considered when creating an application.

Comment: If it will ever be a problem, it's not the idea of using OOP concepts to produce DRYer code but wrong use of them. If the services are almost identical, this is one thing. If you're trying to make Frankenstein's parent class to please all possible childs, it's another thing. I personally see absolutely nothing wrong with this approach when it's done right. And the classes can be refactored any moment to fit the case.

Comment: Thank you @estus, yes the services are identical, just different end point. I'm exporting the classes after injectable but Angular is throwing "Error: Can't resolve all parameters for SomeService" any ideas why?

Comment: Thanks for noticing that, yes, there was a typo. If child class doesn't have its own explicit constructor, @Injectable belongs to parent class (even if it's abstract). See this expanation, https://stackoverflow.com/a/40973412/3731501

Comment: I see, I stand corrected, the sequence of property initialization will prevent url from being setted in parent constructor. There are several ways to make it right, the easiest way is a getter.

Comment: Works great, thank you for all of your help, much appreciated! Always learn something new!

Comment: although this service runs fine in `ng serve` when I run it in production mode `ng serve --prod` I get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined` on `this.httpClient.get(this.URL+"/tags/extended"):this.httpClient.get(this.URL+"/tags")`. I tried adding a constructor to each child class but it didn't like that. Do you have any idea why this type of service would behave differently in prod vs dev ng serve?

Comment: I suspect that this is bug in current AOT implementation. I'd expect them to behave the same way. I suggest to post Angular issue and keep a constructor in child classes as a temporary workaround.

Comment: If I redeclare the constructor in each child class I get the following error `Class 'SomeService' incorrectly extends base class 'ApiService'. Types have separate declarations of a private property 'httpClient'.` I'll open up an issue with the Angular team.