# abstract class constructor throws error

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an abstract class where I mentioned all my `http` calls and while extending it in child services throws error on compile time.

> Can't resolve all parameters for MyService : (?).

baseservice.ts

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

export abstract class BaseService{

    constructor(private http: HttpClient){} //http undefined on compile time                            

    get(){
       return this.http.get()
    }    
}
```

myservice.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class MyService extends BaseService{

  getSource() {
    return this.get('api/Source')
  }
}
```

If I added other injectTokens in constructor of abstract class this leads to `not defined` error

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient, @Inject(APP_CONFIG) private appConfig: any | undefined) {}
```

> Uncaught ReferenceError: http_1 is not defined

if I trying to add Options, it initialising the HttpClient and all working fine

```
HttpOptions = {
   headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Authorization': `Bearer ${this.token}`
   })
```

What is the reason behind this and how to over come this issue while creating instance `HttpClient` without any `InjectTokens` or `httpOtions`.

Comment: you should be using `injector.create()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40972825/inherit-dependency-injection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`http: HttpClient` metadata should be emitted at compilation time on order to be recognized as dependency injection. Due to how emitting of type metadata works, a decorator should be specified on a class that contains metadata.

In a hierarchy of injectable classes that have dependencies annotated with TypeScript types like `http: HttpClient`, **base** class needs `@Injectable()` decorator:

```
@Injectable()
export abstract class BaseService{
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}                       
}

export class MyService extends BaseService {}
```

If child class has its own constructor, it needs `@Injectable()` decorator, too:

```
@Injectable()
export abstract class BaseService{
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}                       
}

@Injectable()
export class MyService extends BaseService {
    constructor(http: HttpClient, private foo: Foo) {
        super(http);
    }                       
}
```

Because of [how `@Injectable` works](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39029435/3731501), it isn't necessary in classes that use explicit `@Inject` annotation.

Answer (score 2):

Your abstract class has a constructor, so...you have to declare the constructor too in the concrete class, and invoke to super:

```
@Injectable()
export class MyService extends BaseService{

  constructor(private http: HttpClient){
    super(http);
  }

  getSource() {
    return this.get('api/Source')
  }
}
```

Comment: Yea, it will leads to import those modules in derived class also I want to avoid that. Is there any possibility of it.

Comment: I had a similar case and Instead of making the service abstract and extend from it made the baseclass a normal service and only added the service as dependency to all users. If you extend the baseclass you need to call the super constructor.

Comment: @tomvangreen  rn main concern is to avoid `super`  if it is not possible I need to follow your suggestion.

Comment: It is not possible, if you extend a class in typescript you always need to call the super constructor. In my case I thought the base class was the better option, but in the end a separate service was the better solution.

Comment: This is not true. First of all, a constructor is inherited in child class. If MyService doesn't need its own dependencies, it doesn't need its own constructor. And `private` modifier in child class will result in compilation error.